# How to detect a touch outside a button (ie. on background)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I am creating a hovering button to present a flying menu like the Inbox app has (and to learn I am not relating on working GitHub code).

So far I just present the button and when the user taps on it a background blurs (and more buttons are shown). Now what I want is that when the user taps outside the button and all other buttons that will be presented (so literally the user touches only on the blurred background) the blur is dismissed. 
But right now every thing I try also includes the buttons as well (tapGestureRcognizer, touchesBegan,...).

I thought that a tapGestureRecognizer added as a subview of the blurEffectView would exclude the menu buttons, but this doesn't work. Actually normally a highlight effect is visible when touch a button, but after adding the tapGestureRecognizer there is no highlight effect on the button, so I guess that the tapGestureRecognizer is on top of everything?

So how could I make sure that only the touched background dismisses the blurred view?

Here is my code so far:

The button action:

```
var blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
...
...

@IBAction func plusButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    blurScene()

    var touch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(dismissBlur))
    blurredEffectView.addGestureRecognizer(touch)

}

func blurScene() {

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
    blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurredEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurredEffectView.alpha = 0
    view.addSubview(blurredEffectView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.blurredEffectView.alpha = 1
    })
}

@objc func test() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.blurredEffectView.alpha = 0
    }, completion: {
        (true) in self.blurredEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

Again showing and dismissing the blurred background works fine and the button stays in focus, but no matter where I tap (background or buttons) the blurred view is dismissed, but I'd like to exclude the buttons, because they get other actions obviously.

Comment: I *think* you have the correct strategy - meaning I think this would work. So my question is whether your issue is with the view hierarchy. If the blurred view is top most, it will *look* like the buttons are working. What is after adding the blurred view you made sure to send it to the back of the hierarchy?

Comment: Since I have a couple of labels in the view I tried to change the zPosition of the button to +20 and used view.insertSubview(blurredEffectView, at: +10) - which worked like before, but the tapGestureRecognizer overlays everything. How can I move that down the hierarchy?

Comment: I almost up voted @PredragSamardzic for the answer but will hold off until you get up your hierarchy correctly. Here are the rules. (1) The *order* of adding subviews dictates the hierarchy. So if you add things in the order of `UILabels` then `blurredView`, then `UIButtons` your hierarchy is the reverse - which I think you want. But you probably have things that will interfere with that - namely adding/removing the blurred view. So: (1a) Could you hide the blurred view instead of adding/removing? I honestly don't know. If not, then....

Comment: (2) Use the easiest combination of `sendSubview(toBack:)` or `bringSubview(toFront:)`. This depends on the number of `UIButtons` versus non-`UIButtons`. It's probably the former - so add your blurred view, then loop among the view's subviews for `UIButtons` and use `bringSubview(toFront:)`. If you need a code snippet for looping and *only* altering the `UIButtons`, let me know and I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line `view.sendSubview(toBack: blurredEffectView)` after `view.addSubview(blurredEffectView)`

Comment: This is not working at all because it moves the blurred view into the background behind everything apparently!?

Comment: In that case, if I understand your hierarchy properly, instead of view.addSubview(blurredEffectView), you could try with view.insertSubview(blurredEffectView, belowSubview: plusButton)

Answer (score 0):

Solving your problem is quite simple actually.

Instead of adding blurView as a subview.

You need to insert blurView below the plusButton.

You can refer to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622598-insertsubview) for further information.

Comment: I had this idea before and used zPositions to place the button at +20 and the blurredEffectView at +10 so that it is below the button, but the tapGestureRecognizer seems to be overlaying everything. My idea was that because it is a subview of blurredEffectView it would be at the sam hierarchy position, but apparently it is still placed on top of everything!?

Comment: Try blurView.userInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: Or you can remove the tapguesture all together and utilize the touches began method and check the location of the touch and add your logic there

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to:

(1) Add a blurred view, which will place it at the top of the view hierarchy, then....

(2) Move all subviews that are a `UIButton` above the blurred view.

```
view.addSubview(blurredEffectView)
for view in view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let button = view as? UIButton {
        view.bringSubview(toFront: button)
    }
}
```

And if you need to be selective after getting the button, you can either check the tag property or the title text.